# Combinatory, expected number of connected nodes. Sum on positive multinominal coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling with the following problem:

### Problem

Consider two sets A and B containing *m* and *n* nodes. These sets are connected by *l* edges. Each edge connects one node from A to one node from B.

Boundary of set A is the subset of its nodes that are connected (by edges) to set B.
I'm looking for the expected size of this boundary.

I would like to use this expected size to answer the question "What is the probability, that a node from A is exactly one edge away from closest node in set B".

### Example

Lets consider sets A and B to have two nodes each.

If there is one edge:
Expected boundary of A is 1.

If there are two edges, there are possibilities:

```
       1)        2)        3)         4)        5)     6)
       A   B     A   B     A   B      A   B     A   B   A    B
       * - *     * - *     * - *      * \ *     * / *   * \/ *
       * - *     * / *     * \ *      * - *     * - *   * /\ *
b(A)=   2          2         1           2        1        2
```

Expected b(a) = 10/6

and so on..

### My tries

What I've considered is representing the problem with a matrix of size *n* x *m* with *l* where each sell is a possible edge. Then *l* cells would be filled. 
There would be: $ |\Omega|={{nm}\choose{l}} $ possibilities.

Then I tried to count number of ways *i* rows can be populated (with *l*) cells to get the probability of boundary size *i*. I assume that would be number of ways different *l* of ${im}\choose{l}$ objects can be placed in different *i* bins where none of them is empty.

I've looked at the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) but here it considers identical objects and thats not the case.

It also looks similar to sum of [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) but with the limitation that counts in each bin ($k_i$ in wikipedia article) must be positive.

But I may be going in the wrong direction entirely. Thank you for replies.

Comment: Just to understand it right, what is the size of the "boundary" if the graph has two or more connected components?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've added an example, hope it clarifies...

Comment: Not clear for me. "Each each is unique" (?) "one node from A can be connected to any number of nodes from B" (and viceversa,  no?) "Connected nodes form a boundary of the set" (are you speaking of the set A?). Is the total number of edges fixed? "Expected number"... with respect of what probability law?

Comment: Not clear for me too. Are you simply asking for the average value of $|f(L)|$ where $f:L\to A$ and $|L|=l,|A|=m$?

Comment: @leonbloy I've updated the definition of edge. Yes, it's boundary of set A. Number of edges is a variable.

Comment: "NUmber of edges is a variable". A random variable (included in the expectation calculation), or rather a parameter (the expectation is a function of it)? Your example suggest the later.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right: given that the number of edges $\ell$ is fixed, there are a total of $m \times n$ pairings possible, so the total number of alternatives is ${mn \choose \ell}$. How many of these involve exactly $k$ elements (out of $m$) from $A$?
This is

$$g_k={m \choose k} \left[ {k\,n \choose \ell}-{(k-1)\,n \choose \ell}+{(k-2)\,n \choose \ell}-\cdots\right]={m \choose k} \left[ \sum_{j=0} {(-1)}^j{(k-j) \,n \choose l} \right]$$

And the expected number is $$\frac{1}{{m\,n \choose \ell}}\sum_k g_k$$

This is, of course, not a complete solution. But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.